# Can two browser windows cause race conditions in synchronous JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, web, thread-safety

I have the following function that synchronizes some locally cached data with my online database.

In the process, existing values are retrieved from the database, added to the locally cached values, and then sent as an update to the database. Because of this summing process, this procedure must not run multiple times in parallel because it could result in invalid values (adding more than it should).

I implemented a locking mechanism using local storage. It seems to work well because JavaScript is single-threaded and runs all the locking code synchronously, even if this function is called rapidly in succession.

The problem is, how do I also make this thread-safe across browser tabs/windows? The way I see it, multiple windows behave like separate threads, taking away the benefit of JavaScript's single-threading approach.

So **1) Is my assumption about multiple browser windows behaving like multiple threads correct** and **2) How do I make my particular code safe across these different threads/processes**?

```
export async function mergeCachedGameStats(supabaseClient: SupabaseClient) {
    const lockKey = "merge_cached_game_stats_lock";

    const lock = localStorage.getItem(lockKey);

    if (lock && (Date.now() - parseInt(lock) > 15_000)) localStorage.removeItem(lockKey);

    if (lock) return;

    localStorage.setItem(lockKey, Date.now().toString());

    try {
        const { data, error } = await supabaseClient?.auth.getSession();

        if (error) throw error;

        const loggedInUser = data.session?.user;

        for (const key of Object.values(gameStatsKeys)) {
            if (!localStorage.getItem(key + "_cached")) continue;

            const gameStats = await loadCombinedGameStats(key, supabaseClient);

            if (loggedInUser) {
                const { error } = await supabaseClient
                    .from("user_profiles")
                    .update({ [key]: JSON.stringify(gameStats) })
                    .eq("id", loggedInUser.id);

                if (error) throw error;
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(gameStats));
            }
            localStorage.removeItem(key + "_cached");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        localStorage.removeItem(lockKey)
    }
}
```